# VS2015 Linking .dll/.so in C++

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have the following files (https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bfhylzb2evrggp/Lib.rar?dl=0)

It contains the header file, .so and .dll file.

I added the aditional paths under C/C++ and Linker (to the dll.s and .h files)
I have also used the sample code in the rar file and VS2015 picks up the code

## include "swi32.h"

But as soon as I try to use a method defined in the headerfile I get the following

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Donald Jansen\Desktop\CPPTest\Swi32Test\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe  1

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WiCreateRawImage@0 referenced in function _main ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Donald Jansen\Desktop\CPPTest\Swi32Test\ConsoleApplication1\Console.obj    1`

I am not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are **implicitly** linking the dll, then you must have also received a .lib file which you need to link with your console application. This should remove the unresolved symbol warning. The operating system loads the DLL when the executable using it is loaded.

If you are **explicitly** linking the dll, then your code should explictly load and unload the DLL to access the exported functions.

The .so you mention probably is a linux shared object file and not useful on windows platform. I may be wrong though.

Comment: I did not recieve a .lib with the sample code, I am going to try and see if I can linkink it explicity, I know that the .so is not the file I must use, it is the .dll I am trying to use but I recieved both

Comment: Explicitly linking seems to be working, heck a pain in the ass but I am getting somewhere